# Spring 4 + WebSocket + SockJS + STOMP Method Not allowed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I've recently developed a system which uses Spring 4, Websockets, STOMP, SockJS. I have successfully managed to create the connection and send/receive messages but in some cases (randomly, i did not manage to identify the reason) I receive "method not allowed" error and no connection is created and cannot send/receive messages.

My initial thought was that there was something wrong with my spring security configuration and changed permissions for /ws path to permitAll but this did not fix the problem.

Suggestions/comments are highly appreciated.

Below you can find:
1) The code i'm using to initialize the connection and callback functions 
2) Error messages displayed on console when this happens

```
//Create stomp client over sockJS protocol
var socket = new SockJS("/(projectname)/ws");

var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.debug = null;

function callback(frame) {
    //implemented logic


function secondcallback(frame) {
    //implemented logic
}

// Callback function to be called when stomp client is connected to server
var connectCallback = function() {
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/test', callback);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/test2', secondcallback);
};

// Callback function to be called when stomp client could not connect to server
var errorCallback = function(error) {
    alert(error.headers.message);
};

// Connect to server via websocket
stompClient.connect("guest", "guest", connectCallback, errorCallback);
```

[image: error message on console]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure it's not your `X-Frame-Options` header?

Comment: check this link https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11496

Comment: Thank you for your comments. i have added the below:


`<headers>
<frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
</headers>`

in my http configuration 

but i'm still getting the error

Comment: Can you examine the **exact** headers actually _received by_ the client and post them?

Comment: Seems like the X-Frame-Options DENY error is gone but other errors appear. Again the error appears at random periods. [Headers](http://i.imgur.com/MHoPWkZ.png) and [Errors](http://i.imgur.com/AAFEPyv.png)

Comment: what do you using as server?
Depending this, you should enabled websocket on server